# setting loses caret position on <pre> element on pressing TAB key

Tags: jquery, html, append, blur, pre

I have `pre` with `contentEditable="true"` on my webpage and I am trying to make it append `"\t"` when I press `<TAB>`. I found some other plugins for that but they were working only on `<textarea>`.

So, the problem is that when I append text to the `<pre>` through jQuery, it loses the caret position. I was sure it was losing focus but it's not. So `$("pre").focus()`, will do nothing.

I tried to blur it first but this is not practical cause the caret will return on different position depending on the browser. some help please... :P,

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/parisk/kPRpj/

Comment: There is certainly something strange happing there, however I would suggest avoiding doing this in the first place. Not only does your code currently only append the tab, even if the cursor is not at the end of the text, but more importantly it breaks accessibly for users who don't (or cant't) use a mouse.

Comment: I should use it because all this is about a source code editor :P.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you're not simply using a `textarea`? Sounds to me pretty much like a `pre` with `contentEditable` set to true...

Comment: Hey, why don't you just read through the code on the jsfiddle.net site? They use editable elements and seem to support the tab key.

Comment: No it's not the same. The way to find the caret position/selection in a pre tag (editable or not it is the same) and a textarea is dramatically different

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/rich-text_editing_in_mozilla) instead. [Here’s a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kPRpj/15/). In short:

```
$("pre").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.execCommand('InsertHTML', false, '\t');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly Try

```
$("pre").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("pre").append("\t");   
    }
});
```

for inserting a tab. it will insert a tab after your cursor

then in chrome

```
var myselection = document.getSelection();
myselection.extend(jQuery("pre")[0].lastChild, jQuery("pre")[0].lastChild.length)
myselection.collapseToEnd();
```

in IE8

```
var myselection = document.selection;
myselection.extend(jQuery("pre")[0].lastChild, jQuery("pre")[0].lastChild.length)
myselection.collapseToEnd();
```

should get you caret at the end.

**(all together)**

```
$("pre").keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode==9) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("pre").append("\t"); 

        var myselection = null;
        if(document.getSelection)
        {
            myselection = document.getSelection();
        }
        else if (document.selection)
        {
            myselection = document.selection;
        }

        if(myselection != null)
        {
            myselection.extend(jQuery("pre")[0].lastChild, jQuery("pre")[0].lastChild.length)
            myselection.collapseToEnd();
         }
    }
});
```

**EDIT**
it would also be safer to add in a test to see if the lastChild is null and other such. Also in the keydown function `jQuery("pre")` would be better to be `jQuery(this)` and put into a variable if you are using more than once. (which the example is but I'm too lazy)

Comment: Sorry man I changed my whole code due to this problem, so now this issue does not exist :-/

Answer (score 0):

To only your question, the jquery caret libraries are pretty good at encapsulating the quirks around the different browsers (namely IE): http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/caret

You could always just use this to get an index of all the tab positions and then clean them later...

Answer (score 0):

James Khoury's answer always puts the caret at the end of the `<pre>`, which is not desirable when the user hits `tab` in the middle of the text.

Here is a modified version tha fixes this issue : http://jsfiddle.net/kPRpj/12/.
It should be fairly trivial to make `tab` indent the line instead of adding a `tab` character at the caret position. To do that, you would replace

```
container.textContent = text.substring(0,start)+'\t'+text.substring(end);
```

with

```
var left = text.substring(0,start);
var lastLine = left.lastIndexOf("\n");
if (lastLine == -1) lastLine = 0;
container.textContent = left.substring(0,lastLine)+'\t'+text.substring(lastLine);
```

I've put [a version](http://jsfiddle.net/kPRpj/13/) that behaves this way on jsfiddle. However you might need to work around some inconsistencies in their management of `'\n\r'`. For example, I see that chromium sees each line as a separate text node, which is rather unexpected. I haven't tested it in other browsers.